# What linux/unix distributions ship with Mono installed?

Tags: java, mono-framework

Just curious.  Also, what distributions ship with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ships with mono installed and java available.

Not sure about others.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark has it backwards.

Regardless almost all distros will have Java & Mono available in the repositories somewhere.  Fedora always comes with Java IIRC and Ubuntu derivitives usually come with Java, Mono is somewhat less used and therefor less included but apg-get install mono (Or whatever) and yum install mono will both set you on track depending on the repository system of your distro.

Also Ubuntu I believe has access to the "real" Java and fedora requires it be downloaded as an extra from Sun/Oracle.  (I usually do this as a developer for testing but the OpenJDK/JRE which is also Oracle/Sun supported will work in 99.9% of cases and will be the only supported version after seven is released IIRC)